# Problem importing CSV attachment into Power Automate

Tags: csv, sharepoint, power-automate

I'm struggling with an automated import (into SharePoint list) of data from a CSV file using Power Automate.

I had successful process that fetched the CSV on OneDrive and separated out the data into an array, importing it into a SharePoint list.

When I then changed the trigger to look for the CSV an attachment from Outlook, I'm having all sorts of encoding issues.

**The start of the process is:**

> When email arrives
>
> ->
>
> Initialise empty String variable (fileContent)
>
> ->
>
> Loop (get attachment content)
>
> Set fileContent to attachment content *(this is where encoding is off)*
>
> -->
>
> Initialise CSV array
>
> value
> = split(decodeUriComponent(replace(replace(uriComponent(variables('fileContent')),'%0D',''),'%0A','#NL#')),'#NL#')
>
> (--> then, several additional steps that work correctly)

[(pictured outline)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKjCK.png)

The reason for the complex expression in the initialisation of the CSV array is to separate the CSV file into component lines, hence encoding and decoding into URI components.

The problem I'm having is that the attachment content is being shown as if the encoding is off [see pictured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9YCC.png).  Thereafter, all the other steps are wrong.  Then I examine the outputs from when the same file is fetched from OneDrive, the output looks correct.  So I tried, instead, to add the attachment to OneDrive and then get the data from OneDrive. But that ended up with the SAME strange encoding.  It's also the same if I don't put the attachment content into a variable first - if I reference it directly at a later step, the encoding looks to be exactly the same.

There doesn't seem to be anything particularly odd about the file. When I look at the contentBytes from the attachment and put it through a base64 decoder, it's fine. But just not within Power Automate.  Is there something additional I need to do to specify encoding?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Having worked with this more, this doesn't occur with a file that isn't UTF16 encoded. But, unfortunately, this process exists because I have to work with the files that are being emailed... which are UTF16. With that in mind, is there a way to work with this file or tell P.A. which encoding it is?

Answer (score 0):

If you had the OneDrive import/parsing working, you may consider just saving the email attachment to OneDrive, doing your .csv import/parsing, then delete the attachment from OneDrive once its successful.

Comment: I tried that approach, too. Saving it to one drive and then reading from it. But the same thing happens - when the file is saved and read, the encoding is just as above. I think perhaps the attachment reading messes up the way the file is saved so it’s not the same as when it’s uploaded directly to one drive without changes.